# Failed to transition out of the state. The state does not point to a next state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-cdk

hi I want to create a step function I which scenario is I want to go Like this there are 2 **scenarios** :

`1st_step --> 2nd step --> if (Job Complete) -- >  special function --> step 3`

**or**

`1st_step --> 2nd step --> step 3`

and I wrote code like this for cdk

```
sfn_step_1.next(sfn_step_2).next(sfn.Choice(self, "Job Complete?").when(sfn.Condition.string_equals("$.is_query", "True"), sfn_special_step ).afterwards()).next(sfn_step_3)
```

In case of "False" I am getting

** Failed to transition out of the state. The state does not point to a next state.**

As I don't want to add state and let it go to step 3 and end . what should I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
step1 = tasks.LambdaInvoke()
step2 = tasks.LambdaInvoke()
step3 = tasks.LambdaInvoke()

sfn_special_step = tasks.LambdaInvoke()
# here you define the next step and it will keep the flow on as you define in the main flow
sfn_special_step.next(step3)  

step1.next(step2)
    .next(
        sfn.Choice(self, "Job Complete?")
            .when(sfn.Condition.string_equals("$.is_query", "True"), sfn_special_step)
            .afterwards())
    .next(step3)
```

Comment: State Machine Definition: 'MISSING_END_STATE: Workflow has no terminal state at null'   . **getting this error**

Comment: Of course, you need to end the flow with success or failure.
`.next(step3).next(sfn.Succeed(self, "Succeed")`.

Comment: jsii.errors.JSIIError: State 'final-process' already has a next state  now this error